# CASE formula evaluates all expressions when 'otherwise' condition is true

Tags: formula, case

I have a case statement that looks like this in a formula variable:

```
    Case (ContractType, 
'Value 1', (VarA / VarB),

'Value 2', (VarA / VarB), 

 VarC / VarA
)
```

where VarA, B & C are numeric (dollar amounts).

Now the problem is that if the ContractType is not Value 1 or Value 2 then VarB is going to be blank or zero but in any case i want & expect the last statement to execute so it should not matter that varB is zero or null.

However, it seems that even though the last statement might, in a given situation, be the correct statement to execute, the formula VarA / VarB is still evaluated which results in an error and the formula does not return the correct result.

If I re-structure the statement to use 'If's instead of a 'Case' then it works fine.  However i prefer to use Case as it is easier to write and more readable, especially as there are quite a few 'Value' statements involved in my real life scenario.

Is there a way to make the Case statement work correctly even if a value used in a part of the case statement that does not (or should not) get executed has a zero or null in it?
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in a formula, one evaluates null using `BLANKVALUE` or `ISBLANK`, at least that's the way the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/customize_functions.htm) recommends.

I would recommend you use a combination of `IF-ELSE` logic along with `CASE`. From your description, it sounds as though `VarB` is the only one that can evaluate to zero, null or empty that's in a denominator of your formulas. If that's not true, then you'll want to modify what's below to add the other variables that can also have the same conditions. Should that occur, you **may** need to nest a 2nd `CASE` statement inside it to cover situations where any of those variables are in the numerator instead of the denominator. That said, I'd expect that any zero or null values would be handled the same by your "default" or "bailout" CASE; making that unnecessary.

You didn't say what the use case was the formula results are applied to so I'm just providing the formula in the context of the question.

**EDIT**

```
IF(!(BLANKVALUE(VarB) || VarB == 0), 
CASE(ContractType, 
'Value 1', (VarA / VarB),
'Value 2', (VarA / VarB),     
 VarC / VarA
),
'Value3' or other formula applied when VarB = 0)
```

I edited the code above to fix an error in the way BLANKVALUE was applied. Second, in response to your comments, I want to explain how the code above works.

In a formula, an `IF` statement is structured like the following. There's boolean test condition that's evaluated followed by a comma. Then there's code that's applied if the boolean evaluates to 'true' (again followed by a comma). Many will often use a fixed value here, but it can be more code instead such as a `CASE` statement. If the condition evaluates to 'false', then any code following the 2nd comma is run. Again that code can simply be the assignment of a fixed value or as opposed to another expression that gets evaluated.

An `If` statement looks like the following: `IF(boolean condition, 'true', false)`. What I did was substitute the CASE statement for the 'true'. So no, the CASE statement doesn't always get evaluated. It only gets evaluated when the boolean condition evaluates to 'true' (when `VarB` is not blank or equal to zero).

**Edit2**

To clarify my comments. The CASE statement is only evaluated when the IF statement evaluates to True. It is not evaluated when the IF statement evaluates to False. As such, it isn't evaluated every time the formula fires, instead only when the IF statement conditions allow it.

As for the CASE statement being evaluated, one could easily construct a formula where there are two CASE statements, one for when the IF statement is True and another for when it's False.

In order for the CASE statements to be evaluated, yes, the operations in each statement must be performed before they can be evaluated so the proper CASE can be chosen. I believe that's the point you were trying to make. I completely understand that the code in each formula *must* be executed in order for the evaluation to take place. It's incumbent upon you to make certain that your code can be handled safely and is populated with the necessary data for that to happen.

One can construct a series of nested IF statements testing each Var for `BLANKVALUE` and equality with `0`. If a Var passes, the full CASE statement is used for the `True`, if it fails, a different CASE statement is used that removes the CASES that would cause problems with formulas that couldn't be resolved. The next variable is then tested for `BLANKVALUE` and equality with `0`. This continues until you've worked your way through all of them. I hope this clarifies my answer and comments for you.

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev, combining ifs & cases is another way.  
But is it really the situation that a CASE statement is evaluated even if not executed as opposed to an IF statement?  If so this would be a bug in Salesforce I would think!

Comment: See my edited answer with corrections to formula and answers to your comments.

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev, I am well aware of how an IF statement works & is evaluated.  As well I understand what you are doing in your example & considered that option in my solution before posting my original question.

My point, which you seem to have missed, is why does the CASE statement not also behave this way & only evaluate the statement that meets the input criteria as opposed to evaluating all of them and, assuming no errors, only EXECUTE of them. 
This to me seems and odd way to make a CASE statement behave and hence may well be a bug in Salesforce.

Comment: If on the other hand there is a way to make a CASE statement evaluate only the part that needs to be executed without wrapping the whole CASE  in IF's then I would would like to know but there probably isn't.

Comment: Above should read:   why does the CASE statement not also behave this way & only evaluate the statement that meets the input criteria as opposed to evaluating all of them and, assuming no errors, only EXECUTE ONE of them.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that. Computers are 'stupid'. They can only do what you tell them to do. CASE statements execute sequentially until a match is found. If this post led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.

Comment: You still don't understand what I am trying to say. I am also well aware that computers are 'stupid'.  
"CASE statements execute sequentially until a match is found".  Yes, once again, i figured as much.  
For that matter IF statements also execute sequentially until a match is found.

The issue is that only the 'query' or value part of a CASE statement should execute. The action part of a CASE statement should only execute or be evaluated more precisely (as with IFs) WHEN the corresponding value clause is the clause that matches the input data.

Comment: Just to be clear, If/Else combinations execute sequentially.

Comment: You're correct. In both situations, only the conditional clause is evaluated sequentially. The action code isn't evaluation until the results of the conditional clause are satisfied to allow further execution of the code..

Comment: You don't seem to get it, this is getting frustrating.  You say 'in both situations..'  NO,NO, NO, this is ONLY happening with the IF statement. The CASE statement evaluates the action statement regardless, it only actions it it it needs to but it EVALUATES it regardless and hence can error out the CASE statement even though that action statement does not need to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting discussion. I have always considered this behaviour as described undesired and indeed buggy. Like in evaluating an IF statement, only the executed part of the CASE should be evaluated IMO but it doesn't.
I sometimes worked around it by adding an insignificant small number to the variable 'VarB' in your example, just to avoid the error to block your chosen strategy. But that is certainly not a clean solution and not always appropriate. I'm afraid you have little other options here than the one crmprogdev suggests here..

Comment: Hi Fred, i did as it happens last year, end up going with what you have also done. That is I set the default value of Var B to be 1 cent wich in the scheme of things is an insignificant amount compared to the values that are in Var B when a record has a contract type that does actually use Var B. Cheers, George